# Why are Seeker Missiles not used more?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, starcraft-terran

why we don't see seeker missile in usage? Especially against Zerg: Hydralisk (with a bunch of friends), Infestor - they will be killed immediately; Mutalisks, Roaches - they will be damaged significantly...

Yes, Raven requires gas, seek missile tech - also, but that will be still valuable...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seeker Missile used to be much more popular in beta.  Since then they have lowered the damage and required research to unlock it.  The combination of these with the fact that seeker missile is slow, dodge-able, and takes a ton of energy to use has made it much rarer.

There are often more effective use of a raven's energy that take precedence over seeker missile, though a well placed seeker missile can still do a lot of damage.

A seeker missile does `100 damage to a radius of 2`.  This can be very devastating against clumped units.

In terms of capabilities to do damage, consider this:  for 50 energy (instead of 125) you can throw down [auto turrets](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Auto-turret).  A non upgraded turret lasts 180 seconds and shoots every .8 for 8 damage.  `(180 * 10 dps) = 1800 damage`
You can throw down 2.5 turrets / seeker missile = `2.5 * 1800 = 4500 damage.`

This is the equivalent of hitting 45 units with a seeker missile!  That is **un-upgraded**

Upgraded turrets last for 240 seconds and benefit from weapon upgrades leading to:

```
(240 * 13.75dps) = 3300 damage
```

You can throw down 2.5 turrets per seeker missile = `2.5 * 3300 = 8250 damage!`
This is the equivalent of hitting 82 1/2 units with a seeker missile!

You can see why turrets are a better raven damage dealing solution.

Comment: While I agree with you, I'll point out that the benefit of seeker missile is that the damage is *instant*. Very seldom are you going to have an autoturret that shoots for the entire length of it's timed life. Point Defense Drone is probably the Raven's best ability, however.

Comment: @Raven a good point, but the damage isn't truly instant.  In fact the missile can be easily dodged by moving the targeted unit out of range, thus wasting the entire seeker missile.  While the auto turret generally doesn't shoot the whole time its damage is instant (if you throw it down it shoots and can't be dodged)  Another reason Turret is a better damage dealer!

Comment: This would be a more effective argument if we were seeing Raven's using turrets regularly instead of HS Missile.  However, that isn't the case.  Instead what we see is few Ravens and the occasional PDD.  If you want to make an argument that HS Missile is being passed up in favor of Turrets you're going to have to show regular turret play.

Comment: @tzenes my point was only to explain why you don't see many seeker missiles.  Seeker missile is a damage dealing attack and thus, in terms of damage dealing options (seeker missile vs turret) the seeker missile is a weaker choice.  Comparing the utility of PDD to seeker missile is an apples to oranges comparison.  He specifically asked why you don't see seeker missiles and in my opinion its because it is the lesser of the two damage dealing attacks a raven can do... Why this warrants down votes I can't be sure

Comment: @tzenes In terms of Ravens as damage dealers I am absolutely saying you see turrets more often then HS missiles.  This doesn't have anything to do with the lack of Ravens in game play. When a raven is tasked with doing damage users favor the use of turrets over HS. (Either by throwing turrets into the mineral line or during large army clashes)

Comment: @aardvark. I realize what it is you are saying, I'm saying that is a bold statement, and requires proof.  I think the reason you don't see HS Missile much is because you rarely see Ravens, and when you do they're rarely in number.  It doesn't matter HSM vs Turret, people just aren't building Ravens...

Comment: @tzenes Aaah, I think I see where our disagreement stems from!  The way I interpret this question is: Why don't I see Raven's use HS missile. You view it as: Why don't I see HS missile.  My answer is specifically raven usage focused, but if they aren't on the map you can't use them :)

Comment: @aardvark, I believe we've reached understanding.  I really think this is kind of a subjective question, to which you provided a very objective answer.  I think that is, in and of itself, laudable, but I'm not sure it fully answers his question.  You are correct in your assessment, but ultimately the correct answer to his question is a matter of player's opinions.

Comment: WTF, seeker missiles can miss? **not much of a seeker** >.>